# Oracle Sql: Ranking which restarts everytime when there are records in between entries

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have a table like below, it is ordered by time:

```
Id    Day      Name      Time 
1     Mon       a       17:30:00
1     Mon       a       17:30:01
1     Mon       a       17:30:02
2     Mon       b       17:30:03
2     Mon       b       17:30:04
1     Mon       a       17:30:05
1     Mon       a       17:30:06
3     Tue       c       17:30:07
3     Tue       c       17:30:08
```

I want rank this by [Id, Day, Name],

However what I need is if there any records in between same type of entries I want the ranking to start from 1 again. Check the example below and please check the entries with Id = 1:

```
Id    Day      Name      Time        Rank
1     Mon       a       17:30:00      1
1     Mon       a       17:30:01      2
1     Mon       a       17:30:02      3
2     Mon       b       17:30:03      1
2     Mon       b       17:30:04      2
1     Mon       a       17:30:05      1
1     Mon       a       17:30:06      2
3     Tue       c       17:30:07      1
3     Tue       c       17:30:08      2
```

I couldn't do this with regular rank and dense-rank. How can I do this? Thank you=)

Comment: seems like a `[gaps-and-islands]` problem.

Answer (score 2):

use `row_number()`

```
with cte as

(
select id,day,name,time,row_number() over(partition by id,name,day order by time) rn1,
         row_number()over(order by time) rn2
from table
) select id,day,name,time,
  row_number() over (partition by rn2-rn1 order by time) as rank
 from cte
 order by time

output
ID  DAY     NAME    TIME    RANK
1   Mon     a   17:30:00    1
1   Mon     a   17:30:01    2
1   Mon     a   17:30:02    3
2   Mon     b   17:30:03    1
2   Mon     b   17:30:04    2
1   Mon     a   17:30:05    1
1   Mon     a   17:30:06    2
3   Tue     c   17:30:07    1
3   Tue     c   17:30:08    2
```

Answer (score 0):

First some suggestions:

1. Don't use reserved words like ID, NAME, DAY, TIME as column names.
2. Provide test data so people can test and show the results of their
   solutions.
3. Give your exact database version number.

Assuming you have at least version 12c, you can treat this as a "row pattern matching" problem:

```
create table t(Id ,   Day  ,    Name ,     Time ) as
select 1,'Mon','a','17:30:00' from dual union all
select 1,'Mon','a','17:30:01' from dual union all
select 1,'Mon','a','17:30:02' from dual union all
select 2,'Mon','b','17:30:03' from dual union all
select 2,'Mon','b','17:30:04' from dual union all
select 1,'Mon','a','17:30:05' from dual union all
select 1,'Mon','a','17:30:06' from dual union all
select 3,'Tue','c','17:30:07' from dual union all
select 3,'Tue','c','17:30:08' from dual;

select * from t
match_recognize(
  order by time
  measures count(*) as "Rank"
  all rows per match
  pattern(a+)
  define a as (id, day, name) = ((first(id), first(day), first(name)))
);

TIME           Rank         ID DAY N
-------- ---------- ---------- --- -
17:30:00          1          1 Mon a
17:30:01          2          1 Mon a
17:30:02          3          1 Mon a
17:30:03          1          2 Mon b
17:30:04          2          2 Mon b
17:30:05          1          1 Mon a
17:30:06          2          1 Mon a
17:30:07          1          3 Tue c
17:30:08          2          3 Tue c
```